# Creating a data driven web front end quickly

Tags: asp.net, database, frameworks

Over the last few years, I can't count how many web front ends I've had to create over a relatively simple database schema to fasciliate data entry. I have to imagine that someone out there has written a framework I can use to simplify the creation of these kind of simple GUIs.

Doing a quick google, the following look like the key players in .net:

- ASP.Net dynamic data framework
- SubSonic
- NakedObjects for .net

Has anyone worked with any of these and have any preferences? More importantly, are there other frameworks that would be good to evaluate in this space?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like the combo: Routing, ASP.NET MVC 2, Linq to SQL and UI templates.  You will find a few Dynamic Data concepts built in to it.  You can bind your classes to html snippets, which pretty much present reusable screen elements.  You can build data validation right on top of the class definitions, which the partial views will honor.  Really fast setups.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out [IronSpeed](http://www.ironspeed.com/) - not free.

Answer (score 0):

I love SubSonic -- you can quickly generate an AutoScaffold which allow editing of all tables in your database or you can use the scaffold control directly in your web pages. This can be skinned and style.  [Subsonic scaffold info here](http://subsonicproject.com/web-forms-controls/the-scaffold/)